# React native array of string to align in horizontal (Please see the below image)

Tags: android, ios, react-native, android-layout, styles

I want to create something like this

[image]

The data I am getting from backend is like this

```
[
"C",
"C++",
//So on
]
```

Comment: This doesn't look like valid JSON array. It should be either array of `strings` or array of `objects`. Something like `["c", "c++"]` or `[{ c: "c" }, { "c++": "c++" }]`.

Comment: I am sorry I have corrected my mistake

Comment: You can use **<com.google.android.material.chip.Chip** so easily display like this. for more details check this https://material.io/components/chips/android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using flexWrap:'wrap'

For Example,

```
<FlatList
      data={data}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
      contentContainerStyle={{ justifyContent: 'flex-start', flexDirection: 
      'row', flexWrap: 'wrap', paddingHorizontal: 20 }}
      renderItem={({ item }) =>
                   <TouchableOpacity style={{ padding: 10 }}>
                   <Text style={{ backgroundColor: '#edf4fa', fontSize: 22, 
                      padding: 10, borderRadius: 10 }}>{item}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
       }
  />
```